# Duvidas Group by (ireport)

Tags: sql

Estou  utilizando a seqguinte query:

```
Select
TAB.DESCRPROD,
PRO.DT_INC,
PRO.QTD_FALT,
PRO.OBS,
PRO.CODPROD,
RETIRA,
PRAZO,
PREV_ENTREGA,
NRO_OF,
NRO_OP,
MODELO,
SEPARACAO,
MONTAGEM,
GAB,
PROD_CLIENTE,
STATUS,
ORIGEM,
SETOR,
(CASE WHEN ORIGEM = 'F' THEN 'FINALIZADO'
when ORIGEM = 'P' THEN 'PRODUÇÃO'
WHEN ORIGEM = 'A'THEN 'ALMOXARIFADO'
ELSE ORIGEM END) AS ORIGEM2
,
(CASE WHEN GAB = '1' THEN 'N/A'
when GAB = '2' THEN 'FAL.'
WHEN GAB = '3' THEN 'OK'
ELSE GAB END) AS GAB2
,
(CASE WHEN PROD_CLIENTE = '1' THEN 'N/A'
when PROD_CLIENTE = '2' THEN 'FAL.'
WHEN PROD_CLIENTE = '3' THEN 'OK'
ELSE PROD_CLIENTE END) AS EMB
from
AD_FALTAPECAS PEC

INNER JOIN AD_PRODUTOS PRO ON
PEC.SEQUENCIAL=PRO.SEQUENCIAL
INNER JOIN TGFPRO TAB ON
TAB.CODPROD=PRO.CODPROD

where

SETOR = $P{P_SETOR} and
ORIGEM != 'F' AND
PRO.STATUS_ENT = 'P'

order by PRAZO
```

Gostaria de adicionar um `Group by PRO.CODPROD`.
Porém quando o faço recebo a mensagem de erro:

> A coluna 'TGFPRO.DESCRPROD' é inválida na lista de seleção porque não
> está contida em uma função de agregação nem na cláusula GROUP BY.

Por favor me ajudem.

Comment: Parece ser somente sobre SQL e voce colocou tags de JavaScript e Java, o que isso tem haver?

Comment: Para que o "group by" ?

Comment: Então no meu relatório eu estou ordenando por Lote produtivo e dentro desse lote tenho vários equipamentos para produzir.  Muitas vezeses um equipamento ou outro tem alguma peça faltando. O ordem by é para agrupar a quantidade de peças repetidas em um mesmo lote.

Comment: Desculpe, eu não fiz curso de nada e não sei nome de linguagem, apenas fui aprendendo por tentativa e erro. Não sabia que era só SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Tens de repetir TODOS os campos apresentados na lista do SELECT.
De forma geral a clausula `GROUP BY` usa-se da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT 
  <Lista de campo a apresentar 0 ou mais>,
  <Lista de funções agregadoras sobre um qualquer campo>
FROM <Tabela ou junções de tabelas>
[ WHERE <FILTRO SOBRE DADOS>]
GROUP BY 
  <Lista de campo a apresentar 0 ou mais>
```